# tweaking of vertical spacing after \bottomrule

Tags: tables, booktabs

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, UTF8, scheme=plain, twoside]{ctexrep}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % uses graphicx
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
%%
%%
%%
%%
%%
%%
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|ccccccccccccccccccccccc|c}
\toprule 
  & \rotatebox{90}{1999}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2000}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2001}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2002}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2003}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2004}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2005}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2006}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2007}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2008}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2009}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2010}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2011}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2012}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2013}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2014}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2015}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2016}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2017}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2018}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2019}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2020}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2021}  
  &  \\
\midrule
1 & C & B & A & D & E & D & E & C & D & E & B & D & B & B & D & A & A & B & D & B & B & A & B & 1 \\
2 & B & A & E & D & D & E & D & B & C & C & D & A & A & D & B & D & E & D & B & B & E & E & A & 2 \\
3 & D & E & A & C & A & E & A & D & E & B & C & E & E & E & E & E & E & B & A & C & D & B & C & 3 \\
4 & E & C & E & B & C & C & B & E & E & B & A & A & E & C & D & C & C & E & D & D & B & D & A & 4 \\
5 & D & C & C & E & E & B & C & B & D & D & D & E & C & D & E & E & B & A & B & B & D & D & D & 5 \\[2ex]
6 & A & B & D & C & D & B & D & A & A & B & A & C & B & A & E & E & D & C & D & A & B & C & E & 6 \\
7 & E & D & C & B & C & D & B & D & B & D & C & D & A & C & A & B & E & C & C & B & B & B & C & 7 \\
8 & D & C & A & D & D & D & A & C & B & A & A & B & E & A & D & C & B & E & D & A & E & E & B & 8 \\
9 & E & B & D & B & E & E & D & D & B & D & B & C & A & B & A & A & B & C & B & E & C & E & D & 9 \\
10& D & D & B & C & C & E & C & B & C & C & D & C & E & D & C & B & C & E & A & E & B & B & D & 10 \\[2ex]
21& A & E & A & D & D & D & E & A & B & B & E & E & B & A & B & D & D & A & A & D & D & B & D & 21 \\
22& D & C & C & C & C & A & A & B & A & A & D & E & B & E & D & B & B & E & C & E & E & C & E & 22 \\
23& E & B & B & E & A & C & E & B & C & E & C & B & A & C & A & A & B & B & D & A & A & A & B & 23 \\
24& A & A & D & C & B & A & A & C & D & C & C & B & C & D & B & A & E & C & C & B & C & A & B & 24 \\
25& B & A & D & B & A & B & B & D & E & E & E & D & D & B & D & E & D & D & A & D & D & A & E & 25 \\
%% \bottomrule
%% \bottomrule \\[1ex]
%% \bottomrule \\[0.5ex]
\bottomrule \\
  & \rotatebox{90}{1999}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2000}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2001}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2002}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2003}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2004}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2005}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2006}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2007}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2008}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2009}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2010}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2011}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2012}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2013}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2014}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2015}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2016}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2017}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2018}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2019}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2020}  
  & \rotatebox{90}{2021}  
  &  \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Code runs fine. But the spacing between the \bottomrule and the texts afterwards is a bit odd.
So does the vertical bar |.

Anyway to make it look like the "top"? Good space and the little gap between the rules.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the `toprule` "to make it look like the "top"" ?

Comment: @Imran Good question, why didn't I think of that!!!!

Comment: In general never use vertical lines with the rules from the `booktabs` packages. It looks bad by design (you hardly ever see vertical lines in any professionally designed table anymore.